# How to change a brush's color

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Ok suppose I have a brush,

```cpp
HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
```

And I want to change it's color.
*Not calling `CreateSolidBrush` and `DeleteObject` on it over and over again.*

Like in this example,

```cpp
#define INFINITY UINT64_MAX // You get the point. I am just calling it many times.

RECT rect = { 0 };
HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0)); // Same brush as the one above.

for(uint64_t i = 0; i < INFINITY; i++){
    SetRect(&rect, 0, i, i, i + 1); // Right angle triangle btw.
    // How would I change the color of the brush?
    
    FillRect(hdc, &rect, brush);
}
```

As shown above, the reason I don't want to use `CreateSolidBrush` and `DeleteObject` again and again, is that it is slow and I need to be able to change the color of the brush quickly.

I have found [`SetDCBrushColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setdcbrushcolor). Which can change the color of the selected brush? But doesn't seem to change my brush even after selecting it to the context.

That's why I'm wondering if there is any alternative to `SetDCBrushColor`.
So that I can use my brush in `FillRect`.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [SetDCBrushColor()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setdcbrushcolor) is the answer.  You just have to redraw.  Which can be expensive :(  Back in the "olden days", a common "trick" was to modify the frame buffer's color table.  Color tables (like buggy whips and engine carburetors) are pretty much obsolete...

Comment: Are you sure `CreateSolidBrush` and `DeleteObject` are really all that slow?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'm not sure, but I think that it's like calling `free` on a pointer, with other stuff as well. `free` is a slow function. So I assumed that calling `DeleteObject` would be slow as well.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Even [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-deleteobject) says that it ***frees*** all system resources associated with that object.

Comment: 1 million brushes created/destroyed in ~170ms on my system.

Comment: @JonathanPotter ~7500ms on my device **(I have 4gb ram)**, but I get your point. I think I might be wrong about it being slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I am so sorry for asking this question. I found the answer.

Here it is:

```cpp
HBRUSH dcbrush = (HBRUSH)::GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH); // Returns the DC brush.

COLORREF randomColor = RGB(69, 69, 69);
SetDCBrushColor(hdc, randomColor); // Changing the DC brush's color.
```

In the above snippet;

Calling [`GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getstockobject#parameters) returns the DC brush.

After receiving the brush, I can change it's color with the above mentioned.
[`SetDCBrushColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setdcbrushcolor)

I would also suggest saving the color like,

```cpp
COLORREF holdPreviousBrushColor = SetDCBrushColor(hdc, randomColor);
SetDCBrushColor(hdc, holdPreviousBrushColor);
```

So that you set the *DC brush* back to it's original color.

---

So now the code snippet in the question would look like,

```cpp
#define INFINITY UINT64_MAX // You get the point. I am just calling it many times.

RECT rect = { 0 };

HBRUSH brush = (HBRUSH)::GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH); 
COLORREF holdPreviousBrushColor = SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));

for(uint64_t i = 0; i < INFINITY; i++){
    SetRect(&rect, 0, i, i, i + 1); // Right angle triangle btw.
    SetDCBrushColor(hdc, /* Any color you want. */);
    
    FillRect(hdc, &rect, brush);
}

SetDCBrushColor(hdc, holdPreviousBrushColor); // Setting the DC brush's color back to its original color
```